# Copy constructor for class with shared_ptr data members?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I know how to write a copy constructor when you have raw pointer data members in a class, but how do you write a copy constructor when you manage these with a shared_ptr?

Is there a `copy()` or `clone()` function which should be called? Interestingly I have never seen such an example.

Comment: Short answer: You don't. The point of a `std::shared_ptr<Obj>` is *its shared*. The default copy-ctor will manage the reference counting for you when the shared pointer member is copied. If you don't want to have a *shared pointer* to an `Obj`, then don't use a `std::shared_ptr<Obj>`. Use a `Obj`. (Or maybe I misunderstood your question/concern).

Comment: As @WhozCraig says, it is automatic.  Unless you need some kind of specialized copy logic for your own class, the compiler-generated default copy constructor and assignment operators should work.

Comment: but what if you wanted to make a deep copy. The members of the object that have shared pointers also need to be cloned in the class's copy constructor.

Answer (score 8):

The copy constructor for `std::shared_ptr` creates a second pointer which shared ownership with the first pointer.  The pointee will be destroyed when all `std::shared_ptr` that point to it are destroyed.

Without a copy constructor explicitly declared, the language specification decrees that a suitable one will be implicitly provided, and that it will call the copy constructors of each member of your class.

So, in other words, the implicit copy constructor provided for your class will call `shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T> &)`, which will create a second share pointer pointing to the same object, and it doesn't look like that's what you want.  If you want a deep copy of the pointee, you will have to declare your own copy constructor that creates one:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(const Foo &other)
      : foobar(new Bar(*other.foobar.get()))
    {}

    shared_ptr<Bar> foobar;
}
```

References:

- [`std::shared_ptr` constructor documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)
- Copy constructor semantics in [C++98 (see section 12.8.8)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) and [C++11 (see section 12.8.16)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

`std::shared_ptr` has its own copy constructor that will handle the reference counting of the managed *shared* data.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int i) : ptr{std::make_shared<int>(i)} {}
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main() {
    Foo f1{0};
    Foo f2{f1}; // Using the implicitly generated copy ctor.
    *f1.ptr = 1;
    std::cout << *f1.ptr << std::endl; // 1 (data is shared).
    std::cout << *f2.ptr << std::endl; // 1 (data is shared).
}
```

If you want your class to have resource *ownership* semantics then simply declare the resource as an object with automatic storage duration.

```
struct Foo2 {
    Foo2(int i) : i{i} {}
    int i; // Automatic object.
};

int main() {
    Foo2 f1{0};
    Foo2 f2{f1};
    f1.i = 1;
    std::cout << f1.i << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << f2.i << std::endl; // 0
}
```